# A moving charge in an uniform magnetic field

Tags: forces

An electron is in a region where there is an uniform magnetic field created by a large disc-shaped magnet. As is well known, if the electron is moving with velocity $\vec v$ parallel to the flat surface of the magnet (ie, perpendicular to the magnetic field) experiment the Lorentz force, $\vec F=q(\vec v\times\vec B)$. But what would happen if the magnet is moving with velocity $-\vec v$  while the electron is at rest? How we can explain the origin of the force? (Just make a qualitative analysis.) Do not use the Lorentz transformation, we want find the physic origin of the force.

Answer (score 2):

The explanation is that the movement of the magnet causes the magnetic field to change, and a changing magnetic field induces an electric field. The relevant equation is $\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{E} = -\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}$. This equation says that a changing magnetic field sources an electric field the same way a current sources a magnetic field (up to a sign). This explains the origin of the force. In principle, it should be possible to derive that the electric field you get in the uniform region is $\vec{v} \times \vec{B}$.

In fact, here is the proof: Before the transformation, in the frame where the magnet is not moving, we have a constant magnetic field and therefore a constant vector potential. When we switch frames, we the vector potential is not constant, and therefore it generates an electric field given by $\vec{E} = -\partial_t \vec{A}$. In the quasi-static approximation, this $\vec{A}$ is just the galilean transformed $\vec{A}$ from the frame of constant magnetic field. Now $\partial_t \vec{A} = -\vec{v} \cdot \vec{\nabla} \vec{A} = -\vec{v} \times (\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{A}) - \vec{\nabla} (\vec{v} \cdot \vec{A}) = -\vec{v} \times \vec{B} -\vec{\nabla} (\vec{v} \cdot \vec{A}) $, where $\vec{v}$ is the velocity of the charge in the frame where it is moving, and therefore minus the velocity of the magnet in th frame where the charge is stationary.

Now we have $\vec{E} = \vec{v} \times \vec{B} +\vec{\nabla} (\vec{v} \cdot \vec{A}).$ Thus we see we have the $\vec{v} \times \vec{B}$ term as expected, but we also have a term that looks like there is a potential of $-\vec{v} \cdot \vec{A}$. This second term is zero in this case because $\vec{A}$ points in the same direction as $\vec{J}$. This term is due to relativistic effects. To see exactly what this term is, recall that $\vec{A}(\vec{r}) = \frac{\mu_0}{4 \pi} \int \frac{\vec{J}(\vec{r}_0)}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}_0|} d \vec{r}_0$ so that $\vec{v} \cdot \vec{A} = \frac{\mu_0}{4 \pi} \int \frac{\vec{v} \cdot \vec{J}(\vec{r}_0)}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}_0|} d \vec{r}_0=\frac{\mu_0}{4 \pi} 4 \pi \epsilon_0 \int \frac{\vec{v} \cdot \vec{J}(\vec{r}_0)}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 |\vec{r}-\vec{r}_0|} d \vec{r}_0 =\frac{1}{c^2} \int \frac{\vec{v} \cdot \vec{J}(\vec{r}_0)}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 |\vec{r}-\vec{r}_0|} d \vec{r}_0  $, so the apparent potential $-\vec{v} \cdot \vec{A}$ appears to be coming from a charge distribution $-\frac{1}{c^2} \vec{v} \cdot {\vec{J}}$. This charge distribution comes about because if you lorentz boost a stream of moving charges, the charges will contract more if you speed them up and hence the density will increase, or they  will "uncontract" if you are slowing them down, and the density will decrease. Thus we can already see there is a problem with non-relativistic electrodynamics. A relativistic treatment would give you the right answer.

Comment: Yes, but if the magnetic field is uniforme, the electron does not feel any change in the magnetic field, the time derivative of B when the magnet moves is zero.

Comment: The electron, however, does feel the *electric* field sourced by the change in magnetic field.

Comment: I'm completely sure that the electron feels a force, an electric force because it is at rest. But in the place the electron resides there is no change in the magnetic field. Therefore, to my opinion it is not clear enough the true origin of the electric field.

Comment: I edited the answer. You can see the derivation now.

Comment: In the first frame S in which the magnet is at rest, the electron feels E=0 and B not null. In S’ moving with v, in which the electron is at rest and the magnet travels with –v, the electron feels E’=gammavxB=vxB’ and B’=gammaB, according to the Lorentz transformation. The forces are F=qvxB and F’=qE’=qgammavxB, obviously different while the lineal momentum Fdt=F’dt’ is conserved of course.
But the problem is to understand the physics origin of the electric field E’. Your approach in the first version in not conclusive to me.

Comment: Any derivative of the current density is null because the magnetic field is uniform, remember continuity of the normal B-component… there is no equivalent magnetization current in the magnet...

Comment: In the improved version, the fundamental point equation rotE=-∂t(B) does not justify the presence of the E field because in the vicinity of the electron the B field does not change with time.

Comment: In response to your first comment, I didn't consider what happens when you treat the problem relativistically, but you are probably right that it doesn't predict the same force on the magnet in each case. In response to your second comment, I don't know what you are trying to say. In response to your third comment, think about the following statement: "the fundamental point equation rotB = mu_0 J does not justify the presence of the B field where there is no current".

Comment: My second comment concerns with the calculation you offered before edit your comment, when calculating the field in terms of the rotational of the current density.With respect to the third comment: Of course B can exist at points where the current density is null, but it is necessary to have current density at same place… In the same manner, the expression rotE=-∂t(B) requires finding where B varies with time.

Comment: What if we suppose that, instead of displacing the magnet with a velocity v, we consider that the magnet (disk-shaped) rotates around the symmetry axis at a distance R from the position of the electron with an angular velocity w=v/R?

Comment: I think in that case you see the same charge density on both discs in the frame that is co-rotating with the discs.

Comment: There is only one disk. My proposal is to consider that, instead of displace it with velocity -v, the disk rotates with an angular velocity in such a manner that the speed of the disk in the area close to the electron would be the same, –v.
I don’t know what means the sentence of “charge density on both disks…”